# SMTP Gmail error with Codeigniter 2.1.3

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

i have seen many post related to this problems, i have done the instruction given but always get the same error..

I want to send smtp gmail using Code Igniter 2.1.3, this is the code :

```
class Email extends CI_Controller{

function index(){

$config = Array(
'protocol'      => 'smtp',
'smtp_crypto'   => 'ssl',
'smtp_host'     => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'smtp_user'     => 'myEmail@gmail.com',
'smtp_pass'     => '***********',
'smtp_port'     => 25,
'mailtype'      => 'text',
'smtp_timeout'  =>  15, 
'charset'       => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);

$this->email->set_crlf("\r\n");
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from("myEmail@gmail.com", "myName");
$this->email->to("myEmail@gmail.com");
$this->email->subject("Email Test");
$this->email->message("This is email test");

if($this->email->send()){
    echo 'Email Send';
    }   else{
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```

and the error always like this,

```
Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:25 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. )
```

Please help me fixing this error, thanks :)

Comment: If my answer is useful to u plz accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable your ssl in php.ini file in your server configuration and you can check whether it is enabled or not if you are using Xampp server. In that go to PHP info search for ssl.........

You need to remove ; before extension=php_openssl.dll this line in php.ini file.

You need to enable OpenSSL........

I faced this error recently.There is a small mistake in your code........

```
function sendMail()
{
    $config = Array(
  'protocol' => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
  'smtp_port' => 465,
  'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com', // change it to yours
  'smtp_pass' => 'xxx', // change it to yours
  'mailtype' => 'html',
  'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
  'wordwrap' => TRUE
);

        $message = $this->load->view('upload_success','',TRUE);
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
      $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
      $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
      $this->email->to('yyy@gmail.com');// change it to yours
      $this->email->subject('Resume from JobsBuddy for your Job posting');
      $this->email->message($message);
      if($this->email->send())
     {
      echo 'Email sent.';
     }
     else
    {
     show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }

}
```

This is a working code which i am using after i solved the problem which u r facing.....

Comment: i've tried your codes, but have the same error, i have enabled the open ssl extension on my php.ini..

Comment: how can u say u r enabled u r openssl in enabled . Do u have proof. Check the localhost. PHP info tab search for openssl. you will find enabled.

Comment: i've checked phpinfo, the opensll support is enabled, i'm using wamp server.

Comment: k check for enabled sockets streams.........i am also using xampp server in windows.