# Sending mail using dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DOMPDF - attach created PDF to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958416/dompdf-attach-created-pdf-to-email)

I want to send an email instantaneously once PDF is generated.
Have ver. dompdf_0-6-0_beta3 of DOMPDF and php ver 5.2 . Able to generate PDF as required. But can anyone please help me as how to send mail with generated pdf as attachment.

Comment: How much you achieve up-till now ? Have you able to get your pdf generated & save in your system ? Show your code & add more description in your question please.

Comment: Hi Rikesh, Yes I am able to save the generated pdfs on my  system

Comment: I done this same thing in my application.........are you doing it in server or local host.....

Comment: @ Alphamate, thanks, just going thru that link,, cheers :)

Comment: @venky, its on localhost am trying!!

Comment: did you set mail settings to send mail from your application.......

Comment: @venky, no, what are the settings do i need to have, pls let me know

Comment: require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php"); 
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$html = '</html1>';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF(); 
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("bikes.pdf"); currently am just printing it with these

Comment: Please go through this link which i previously answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469891/smtp-gmail-error-with-codeigniter-2-1-3/13469988#comment18493201_13469988

Comment: please go through above link and try to send a general mail....

Comment: no venkat, not able to sent!! I even tried with this basic mail sending option but its not wrking <?php
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>

Comment: what error you are getting.......

Comment: <?php
//define the receiver of the email
$to = 'xxx@gmail.com';
//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'Test email'; 
//define the message to be sent. Each line should be separated with \n
$message = "Hello World!\n\nThis is my first mail."; 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: xxxx@gmail.com\r\nReply-To: xxx@gmail.com";
//send the email
$mail_sent = mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
?>

Comment: I am getting below error for above code!! Do i need to change some settings @ php.ini  --> PHP Warning:  mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Comment: you need to change settings in php.ini file obviously......first search in google how to send an email from codeigntier and write code to send a general email......

Comment: ; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from = me@example.com There changes are already done in php.ini. ok i'll check once @codeigntier

Comment: yes venkat, thanks a lot for your info and time!!

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did in my application please go through it and if you have any doubts let me know.

I am assuming you can able to send mail from your application.

```
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
$file_location is the path where you saved your pdf file in your local host.
file_put_contents($file_location,$pdf);

Now call your mail function like this.
sendMail($from,$to,$subject,$message,$file_location);

       function sendMail()
      {
       $config = Array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com', // change it to yours
                'smtp_pass' => 'xxx', // change it to yours
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                'wordwrap' => TRUE
               );


       $this->load->library('email', $config);
       $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
       $this->email->from($from); // change it to yours
       $this->email->to($to);// change it to yours
       $this->email->subject($subject);
       $this->email->message($message);
       $this->email->attach($file_location);
       if($this->email->send())
       {
          echo 'Email sent.';
       }
       else
       {
          show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
       }

     }
```

Now write a mail function like i mentioned in the comments.